# How to display data by passing it through props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a TeamsPage component and I am passing firstName as prop to PlayerName and I want to display it in table component but I am getting error no valid react child components.

console.log(players) i.e players is array with 5 elements and each array element has firstName, lastName, email etc key-value pairs.

Code:

```
const PlayerName = (name) => (
  <td>{name}</td>
)

const TeamsPage = ({isLoaded, teamIdStr}) => {

let teamId = new Mongo.ObjectID(teamIdStr)
let teamInfo = Teams.findOne({_id: teamId})
let players = Players.find({}).fetch()

console.log(players)

return(
   <div>
     <div className="cardHeader">
       <h4>Team Name</h4>
       <div className="cardContent">
         <div className="table-responsive">
           <table className="table">
             <thead>
               <tr>
                 <th scope="col">#</th>
                 <th scope="col">Name</th>
                 <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                 <th scope="col">Heading</th>
               </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
               <tr>
                 <th scope="row">1</th>
                 {players.map(val => <PlayerName name={val.firstName}/>)}
               </tr>
             </tbody>
           </table>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 )
}
```

Comment: try `return <td>{name}</td>`

Comment: Assuming PlayerName is its own react component then you simply need to return it.  So `{players.map(val => <PlayerName name={val.firstName}/>)}` becomes `{players.map(val => return <PlayerName name={val.firstName}/>)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your have a function called `PlayerName` which receives a name parameter.

```
const PlayerName = (name) => (
    <td>{name}</td>
)
```

And you're calling it as a JSX tag, so remember that in reality the parameter `name` is an object, because when you're calling `<PlayerName name={val.firstName} />`

It receives the whole object as a parameter.

So you have both ways to display the name

Destructuring Example:

```
 const PlayerName = ({ name }) => (
    <td>{name}</td>
 )
```

or

Accessing the prop Example:

```
const PlayerName = props => (
    <td>{props.name}</td>
 )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change your component to:

```
const PlayerName = (props) => (
  <td>{props.name}</td>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or like this

```
const PlayerName = ( {name} ) => (
  <td>{name}</td>
)
```